# Kick a client from server

Tags: c, sockets, unix

there's a simple way to kick a client from a server when a timeout occours? The socket is TCP

Answer (score 2):

Just `close(2)` the file descriptor and stop reading from it.

Comment: but if server close the file descriptor's client, client will not terminates until next operation on file descriptor of server (when the write fail). I would terminate client immediatly when server kick him

Comment: @giozh Actually, when the socket is closed the socket, on the client side, will become readable and the next call to `read` or `recv` will return zero which signifies a clean close from the other side.

Comment: @giozh In TCP terms there's no such thing as "kick". You can merely declare you won't be sending anything else; the client is free to keep its side open.

Comment: @cnicutar i don't know it :D thanks for information. So, i'll just keep the code like actually is! thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

The term *kick* is vague. You can usually force the server TCP stack to reset the connection by enabling the `SO_LINGER` option with a time out of `0`, and then shutdown the socket. An example below (sans error checking).

```
struct linger lo = { 1, 0 };
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &lo, sizeof(lo));
shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
close(sock);
```

The explicit call to `shutdown` is not necessary if you are certain the `sock` has not been duplicated.